# How do I iterate through a QuerySet of a QuerySet?

Tags: django, loops

I'm trying to iterate through a `Review` QuerySet associated to an `Album` QuerySet in order to gather the total amount of ratings within the `Review` QuerySet. (9 + 8 + 7 + 9 = 33, for instance.)
Here are my models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # image =
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 11)],
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(1)],
        default=10,
    )
        ...

class Review(models.Model):
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 11)],
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(1)],
        default=10,
    )
        ...
```

Here are my attempts at `for` loops to try and get these totals:

```
# Attempts working off of: `all_albums = Album.objects.all()`

# Attempt 1
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     review_ratings_amount = album.review_set.rating.all()
...     print(review_ratings_amount)

# Attempt #2
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     review_ratings = album.review_set.filter("rating")
...     print(review_ratings)

# Attempt #3
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     review_ratings = album.review_set.get(rating)
...     print(review_ratings)

# Attempt #4
>>> for album in album_ratings:
...     review_ratings = album.review_set.get("rating")
...     for rating in review_ratings:
...             print(rating)

# Attempt 5 (this was an attempt to see if ANYTHING would return, and I actually got some QuerySets in return so I think
# this one might be in the vicinity of the right track)
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     print(album.review_set.values())

# Attempt #6
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     print(album.review_set.get('rating'))

# Attempt #7
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     items = Album.objects.all().values()
...     for item in items:
...             print(item.review_set)

# Attempt 8
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     review_ratings = Album.objects.get('review').values()
...     print(review_ratings)

# Attempt 9
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     review_ratings = Album.objects.get('review.rating')
...     print(review_ratings)

# Attempt 10
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     review_ratings = Album.objects.get('review.rating')
...     for review in review_ratings:
...             print(dict(review))
```

All of the attempts above returned errors, except `# Attempt 5` which returned querysets of all of the values within `album.review_set.values()` -- so I think I might be near the "right track" with this code.

But can anyone lead me to any helpful documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the object being returned when you access `review_set`. It is a QuerySet as you understood, but some of your attempts try to access a `rating` attribute. If you think of querysets as a list of objects, you're trying to get the rating of a list, instead of rating for each object in that list.

The following will get you what you want although there are more ways to achieve the same.

```
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     review_ratings = album.review_set.values_list("rating", flat=True)
...     print(review_ratings)
...     total_ratings = sum(review_ratings) # to get the sum total of ratings
```

[`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for a queryset returns tuples of the passed attributes and the `flat=True` will return single values instead of 1-tuples (e.g., [1] instead of [(1,),]) if only one attribute is passed to values_list.

Comment: I used your solution and got what I needed. But I still have a problem: I'm trying to get the averages from both an Album and its Reviews to build a list of "Highest Rated" albums by the averages. I'm using this code you helped me build: ```all_albums = Album.objects.all()   for album in all_albums:   total_ratings_count = album.review_set.count() + 1   album_rating = album.rating   review_ratings = album.review_set.values_list("rating", flat=True)   total_review_ratings = sum(review_ratings)   total_ratings = album_rating + total_review_ratings ``` (con't)

Comment: ```rating_avg_result = total_ratings / total_ratings_count   rating_avg = round(rating_avg_result, 1)``` But then I can't use `rating_avg` to do this: `ratings_list = Album.objects.all().order_by('-rating_avg')[0:5]` Obviously I can't use `rating_avg` because it's not a field in my Album model. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is going by memory so I may have this wrong...

`album.review_set` is an object manager and not a queryset.  Another example of an object manager is `Album.objects`.  To get a `QuerySet` from an object manager you need to use something like `.all()` or `.values()` (as you discovered), an iterative context, etc.

So, not what you want, but this should run:

```
for album in all_albums:
    for review in album.review_set.all():
        print(review.rating)
```

You probably want to use the "aggregate" database functions to get average reviews or something like that.

**EDIT:**

The [Django docs have some good examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards) of what you're doing with ratings...

```
>>> from django.db.models import Avg
>>> Album.objects.aggregate(average_rating=Avg("review__rating"))
```

Then each `Album` object will have an `average_rating` attribute.  (though, I haven't testing this)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @AndrewRea  Please upvote answers you found helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for album in all_albums:
...     print(album.review_set.values())
```

Ok, you have a mystery object, `album`, with a `review_set` attribute,
and you're not sure how to interact with either of them.
Here is some advice.
tl;dr: `dir()`, `type()`, and `help()` are your friends.

Start with the class definition.
You posted some of it, but I don't notice `review_set` in there.
Perhaps it is part of the `...` ellipsis.
Read its source -- you may find some clues there.

Ask your RDBMS for the table schema,
or investigate it with simple SELECT * queries.
We expect the model objects to resemble what the database is storing.

---

Imagine you have a completely unknown object, and there's no documentation website.
How shall we investigate it to find out what it's good for?

Preliminaries: you will find `pp` convenient, so pull it in.

```
>>> from pprint import pp
```

(1.) Ask what `type` the object is:

```
>>> type(album)
```

You could also `print(type(album))`.
In your case `album.review_set` might be the
object you're more interested in.

(2.) Request `help` on the object:

```
>>> help(album)
```

If there's a """docstring""", it will be displayed.
Most objects have a bunch of attributes, each having its own docstring,
and they will be displayed as well.

(3.) Examine the object's attributes:

```
>>> pp(dir(album))
```

You don't *need* to pretty print the `dir` output,
but it will be a whole lot more readable that way.

Each attribute is an object in its own right,
and you can go on to examine any that prove interesting.
For example, your next step might be to look at `pp(dir(album.review_set))`.

Good luck [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)!

Comment: @AndrewRea I upvoted this as it's good general advice.  It doesn't answer your specific question, but this is the process I go through when trying to debug an issue I can't figure out (especially when docs are sparse).  `type(album.review_set)` would have revealed it was an object manager and not a queryset.